# How can I type a backtick using a German keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard

I am trying to type a backtick (`` ` ``) using a **German keyboard**.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be found at the top-right corner of the keyboard while holding down shift.  Type a space afterwards to exit dead key status.

[image]

Comment: Was TomGewecke someone that commented before and deleted it all? This is the first time I'm seeing all of this since my answer...

Comment: Yes, your keyboard was for Windows, then haykam added an erroneous one for Mac, and after fixing it all the comments no longer made any sense so I deleted mine.

Comment: @TomGewecke I thought you didn't want Windows.

Comment: @haykam For correct keyboard diagrams, you must use https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794  and not screenshots on your machine.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for adding the correct image.

Comment: With this one need to click the '`' key twice. How could one type with one shot?